# CSS Grid space-between not working as expected when content reaches a certain limit

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I want to create a section with tabs that becomes an "accordion" in small screens, so instead of defining the tabs bar first and then the content of each tab I'm placing the link to the tab and the content of that tab right after the link and then using CSS Grid I'm positioning the active tab after all the links in the tab bar to have the links in the first row and the active tab in the second row.

You can see that working here:

https://codepen.io/rbournissent/pen/PByXxM

```css
div {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, auto);
  grid-row-gap: 80px;
  grid-template-rows: 40px 1fr;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

a {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

article {
  display: none;
  grid-column: 1 / 5;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

article.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  <article class="active">
    Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore vero, eius quae placeat.
  </article>

  <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  <article>
    Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quam tempore ipsum ipsa assumenda id rerum a voluptate ipsam nemo, repellat, quisquam nulla, ullam minima cumque obcaecati molestias veritatis cum iusto!
  </article>

  <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  <article>
    Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum nesciunt facilis temporibus quaerat maiores aut, voluptates recusandae voluptatem corporis adipisci quia, nisi mollitia! Cum delectus earum sapiente distinctio tenetur iusto?
  </article>

  <a href="#">Link 4</a>
  <article>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sit culpa optio accusamus soluta nemo, porro repellendus! Quisquam corrupti, hic praesentium ipsa, voluptate, non laudantium quae sit eum dolorum illo sed.
  </article>
</div>
```

*The problem is what happens when the content of the article grows*. **The links get stretched to fill the whole row and space-between is no longer working** (i.e. there is no more space between them):

https://codepen.io/rbournissent/pen/qyJLwy

```
<div>
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <article class="active">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus ab beatae sed maxime. Amet quam, error atque alias velit dicta officia et optio. Quidem tempora officiis minus laudantium! Beatae, eveniet!
    </article>
  
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <article>
        Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quam tempore ipsum ipsa assumenda id rerum a voluptate ipsam nemo, repellat, quisquam nulla, ullam minima cumque obcaecati molestias veritatis cum iusto!
    </article>
  
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    <article>
        Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum nesciunt facilis temporibus quaerat maiores aut, voluptates recusandae voluptatem corporis adipisci quia, nisi mollitia! Cum delectus earum sapiente distinctio tenetur iusto?
    </article>
  
    <a href="#">Link 4</a>
    <article>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sit culpa optio accusamus soluta nemo, porro repellendus! Quisquam corrupti, hic praesentium ipsa, voluptate, non laudantium quae sit eum dolorum illo sed.
    </article>
</div>
```

The only difference is the amount of text (content) in the active article (tab).

Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: Can we wrap the `<a>` inside a `div`.?

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't add space between the cells: https://codepen.io/rbournissent/pen/VBERrP
(see the difference with space-between working properly: https://codepen.io/rbournissent/pen/PByXxM where the links are evenly distributed with the right gap in between)

Comment: Oh, sorry. I'm trying to avoid that because then with media queries I want to convert it into an "accordion" where you can expand/collapse the tabs. Here is the implementation with the media query: https://codepen.io/rbournissent/pen/BPqgRY

Comment: I didn't get it. What are you trying to avoid?

Comment: There was a comment before that was removed. I'm trying to avoid to wrap all the links with a div because then I need to have "links, tab, links, tab, links, tab, ..."

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work for you:

> The fix was simple just added `width:15vw;` to the `<a>` so the width
>   dont get changed.

```css
div {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, auto);
  grid-row-gap: 80px;
  grid-template-rows: 40px 1fr;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

a {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width:15vw;
  margin-right: 11.2vw;
}
a:nth-last-child(2){ margin-right:0;}
article {
  display: none;
  grid-column: 1 / 5;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

article.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  <article class="active">
    Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore vero, eius quae placeat.
    Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore vero, eius quae placeat.Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore vero, eius quae placeat.Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore vero, eius quae placeat.Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore vero, eius quae placeat.
  </article>

  <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  <article>
    Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quam tempore ipsum ipsa assumenda id rerum a voluptate ipsam nemo, repellat, quisquam nulla, ullam minima cumque obcaecati molestias veritatis cum iusto!
  </article>

  <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  <article>
    Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum nesciunt facilis temporibus quaerat maiores aut, voluptates recusandae voluptatem corporis adipisci quia, nisi mollitia! Cum delectus earum sapiente distinctio tenetur iusto?
  </article>

  <a href="#">Link 4</a>
  <article>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sit culpa optio accusamus soluta nemo, porro repellendus! Quisquam corrupti, hic praesentium ipsa, voluptate, non laudantium quae sit eum dolorum illo sed.
  </article>
</div>
```

This issue occurred as you are using `display: grid;` the width of the content in `article` is effecting the `a` even the if the text in the `article` it affects the `a` so, in my opinion, it's better to go with my solution.

Hope this was helpfull for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This approach still have the problem where the cells are using the whole space to fill the row. See how with this solution you have an empty space after the 4th link. With space-between, the last link should be at the very end of the row (and the space between links should be the same)

Comment: @RodrigoBournissent updated my answer please do check.

Answer (score 0):

If you're allowed to use grid-template-areas, you can try this out:

```css
.accordion {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 25% 25% 25% 25%;
  grid-template-rows: 30% 70%;
  grid-template-areas:
    "l1 l2 l3 l4"
    "a a a a";
}

a {
  margin: 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
}

a:nth-of-type(1) {
  grid-area: l1;
}

a:nth-of-type(2) {
  grid-area: l2;
}

a:nth-of-type(3) {
  grid-area: l3;
}

a:nth-of-type(4) {
  grid-area: l4;
}

article {
  display: none;
}

article.active {
  text-align: justify;
  padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
  display: block;
  grid-area: a;
}
```

```html
<div class="accordion">
  
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  <article class="active">
    Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore vero, eius quae placeat.Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore vero, eius quae placeat. Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet     consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore vero, eius quae placeat.Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore vero, eius quae placeat.
  </article>
  
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  <article>
    Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore vero, eius quae placeat.Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore vero, eius quae placeat.
  </article>
  
  <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  <article>
    Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore vero, eius quae placeat.Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore vero, eius quae placeat.
  </article>
  
  <a href="#">Link 4</a>
  <article>
    Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore vero, eius quae placeat.Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore vero, eius quae placeat.
  </article>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this approach still have the issue when you use `justify-content: space-between;` (and there is a lot of content inside the active article/tab)

Comment: I don't seem to get you. Here's a pen where I used both `justify-content: space-between;` and a lot of content inside. And I still cannot spot the issue. https://codepen.io/devnathjoydeep/pen/QBZXeP

Comment: Maybe is easier to see it if you remove the margin (`margin: 20px;`) from the links. There is no space between the links, the "grid items" are using the whole space, even if you use `grid-template-columns: repeat(4, auto);` instead of `grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 25%);`. I want the links to use only the space each of them needs and still be equally separated from each other (this is what space-between does).

Comment: To see the difference between [this](https://codepen.io/rbournissent/pen/PByXxM) and [this](https://codepen.io/rbournissent/pen/qyJLwy) maybe you need to add more content in the active article of the second link (the content has to use at least to lines inside the article to reproduce the issue where the links suddenly start using all the space available)